# Using byte in java

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion, byte

How does the code in java

```
     for (int a=0; a < 256; a++) {
        sta[a] = (byte)a;
    System.out.println(a);
    }
```

prints 0 to 255 when the maximum value if a byte is 127.

How to convert int to unsigned byte using "& oxff" ?

Comment: Because you are printing `integers` and not `bytes`.

Comment: Try `System.out.println((byte) a);`

Comment: System.out.println(sta[a]);

Comment: thanks, got it. i didnt really pay attention to the variable i was printing.

I want to work with unsigned byte actually. Since java doesn't have that how can i use int as unsigned bytes by AND-ing with OxFF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are casting the integer variable a into a byte variable being stored in an array. However the variable you are printing is a which still is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

the width of byte is 8 bits while integer is 32 bits. An you can convert for example

```
int a = 23;
byte b = (byte)a;
```